# Django: Sort articles by hourly/daily views (trending)

Tags: python, django, orm

Suppose we have a blog with 100 articles.
How can we let the users sort articles (objects) by the number of views (field) in the last hour/day/week/month?

Can we implement something that makes the field `views_today` such that it becomes `0` every hour?

Comment: have you tried anything ? you basically have a view count field in your Article object anyway, you can do query to filter by hour/day/week/month, if you want to change data every intervals then it's called [scheduling tasks](https://medium.com/@kevin.michael.horan/scheduling-tasks-in-django-with-the-advanced-python-scheduler-663f17e868e6)

Comment: @LinhNguyen, thanks. I think that should work.